# Отражаются(,) как в зеркале

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

> В делах, поступках, поведении бригадира(,) как в зеркале(,) отражаются его отношения к коллективу, в котором он трудится.

Нужны ли выделенные запятые? Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь "как в зеркале" = "ясно, полно" (из словаря: Лебедева Л.А. *Устойчивые сравнения русского языка*. М., 2015).

Запятые не нужны.

Comment: Вот похожая цитата из Д.Э. Розенталя: "В ней [рекламе — grizzly], как в зеркале, отражаются все принципы и задачи развития народного хозяйства". Может ли постановка запятых в обсуждаемом предложении быть факультативной? (Я поддержал оба ответа — и за, и против).

Comment: Если автор захочет выделить этот оборот интонационно, запятые возможны. Меня в ответе Риммы Михайловой резануло вот это:  _"**Делаем вывод:** как в зеркале — сравнительный оборот, выделяем…"_ А ведь из того, что говорилось в ответе перед этой фразой, такой вывод-то, по-моему, никак не следовал. Скорее наоборот...

Comment: В благодарность за ссылку на словарик отмечу ответ галочкой. Однако, на мой взгляд, тут все-таки не «ясно, полно», а именно метафоричное сравнение.

Answer (score 2):

[**как в зеркале**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/283857/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA), *наречие*, синоним — зеркально.

[**отражаться**](http://%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5;%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F.)
4. *перен.* Получать внешнее проявление; обнаруживаться.

**1.** Мне кажется, что предложение нуждается в правке.

*Отражаются его отношения в коллективе* ("множественное" действие) — отношения с разными людьми внутри коллектива.

*Отражается его отношение к коллективу* — отношение во всему коллективу (как единому целому).

**2.** Глагол "отражаться" в этом предложении означает *проявляться, обнаруживаться, показываться* — никакого отношения к отражению в зеркале и к зеркальности он не имеет.
Делаем вывод: **как в зеркале** — сравнительный оборот, выделяем его запятыми (можно даже тире — для "разбавления" запятых).

**3.** Я бы написала это предложение так:
В делах, в поступках, в поведении бригадира, как в зеркале, отражается его отношение к коллективу, в котором он трудится.

*[Как в зеркале](https://books.google.ee/books?id=eHPvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=oVmotRqSXI&sig=1PYajCQXMQ8tPtpfqbqG1NGrDXQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu7qXjqZ3eAhWFEywKHXGtBvkQ6AEwEXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5&f=false), там отразилось то, что больше всего волнует: любовь и смерть, литература и жизнь, поиск себя, попытка понять другого. Как в зеркале, там есть немножко от каждого из нас. И, как в зеркале, — там есть что-то ещё, что не увидели авторы, но, быть может, увидят читатели — если посмотрят в зеркало с другой точки зрения.*

Answer (score 0):

Склоняюсь к тому, что запятые не нужны. Я не согласен с теми, кто видит здесь сравнение (отражение в делах сравнивается с отражением в зеркале -?!). Нужно отдельно рассматривать словосочетание "как в зеркале", а оно является устойчивым выражением, потерявшим признаки сравнительного оборота (отражается как в зеркале = отражается ясно).

Вот пример, в котором, в отличие от нашего, есть сравнение (воспоминания сравниваются с зеркалом):

> [Вопрос № 223009](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=223009)
>   Помогите,пожалуйста, не совсем ориентируюсь в правописании сравнительных оборотов. В его воспоминаниях, **как в зеркале**, отражается бурная эпоха. Надо ли выделять оборот, или в данном случае он тесно связан со сказуемым и выделения не требует?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Comment: *Для сравнения.* — Поясните, пожалуйста, смысл этого сравнения. Я вижу в нём только противоречие с ответом. Вот ещё цитата из Розенталя: "В ней [в рекламе — grizzly], как в зеркале, отражаются все принципы и задачи развития народного хозяйства". Рискну предположить, что постановка запятых в предложении из вопроса может быть факультативной.

Comment: *отражение в делах сравнивается с отражением в зеркале -?!* — Нет, по аналогии: дела, поступки, поведение бригадира сравниваются с зеркалом, в котором отражаются...

Comment: @grizzly В вопросе № 223009 есть сравнение (воспоминания сравниваются с зеркалом), в нашем случае я такого сравнения не вижу (поступки сравниваются с зеркалом?). Впрочем, если автор так видит, то нужно запятые ставить.